# pub get failed (1; So, because fstore depends on both flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1 and cached_network_image 2.5.1, version solving failed.)

Tags: flutter, dart

```
[![Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on async 2.6.1 and fstore depends on async 2.5.0, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
```

So, because fstore depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in testupdate...
pub get failed (1; So, because fstore depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyW92.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyW92.png)

> Code was running on master channel but when I changed channel to dev after that i'm Getting this error on each channel
> When I upgrade this Async I get more errors

[image: After removing Async]

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are having a flutter package where its dependency needs a higher version than you need. This might be due to your dependencies have updated.

Use
`flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0`
`cached_network_image: ^3.0.0`
Now both supports `Null safety`. Please use updated packages from https://pub.dev/packages

Comment: it was due to wrong flutter version I have downgraded and it started working